# Testing Promises vs Lock performance

Tags: performance, scala, locking, concurrency, promise

I'm not sure if my lock usage is correct and safe. I wanted to know what will be best approach to deal with situation when one thread have to wait for being initialized by another so I written this test:

```
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock
import java.util.{TimerTask, Timer, Date}
import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future, Await}
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration

class I{
  private var i:Int = 0
  def inc() = i+=1
  def value = i
}

trait Test {
  def doSomething():Unit
  def initialize(i:I):Unit
  def result:Int
}

case class TestLocks() extends Test{
  var ref:I = null

  val lock = new ReentrantLock
  val refInitialized = lock.newCondition()

  def doSomething(){
    lock.lock()
    try {
      if(ref==null) { refInitialized.await() }
      ref.inc()
    }
    finally {
      lock.unlock()
    }
  }

  def initialize(i:I){
    lock.lock()
    try{
      ref = i
      refInitialized.signal()
    }
    finally {
      lock.unlock()
    }
  }

  def result = ref.value
}

case class TestPromises() extends Test{
  val iPromise = concurrent.promise[I]
  def doSomething(){
    val i = Await.result(iPromise.future,Duration.Inf)
    i.inc()
  }

  def initialize(i:I){
    iPromise.success(i)
  }

  def result = Await.result(iPromise.future,Duration.Inf).value
}


object TestRunner{
  def apply(test:Test):Long = {

    val initializationTimeout = 10
    val timer = new Timer()
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask {
      def run(){
        test.initialize(new I)
      }
    },initializationTimeout)

    val start = new Date().getTime

    1 to 1000000 foreach (i=>{
      test.doSomething()
    })
    val end = new Date().getTime

    val duration = end-start-initializationTimeout
//    Console.println(test+" result: "+test.result+" in: "+duration+"ms")
    duration
  }
}

object Tests {
  def run() {

    def average(l: => Long) =
    {
      val vals = 1 to 100 map(_=>{l.toDouble})
      vals.sum/vals.length
    }

    def averageAsync(l: => Long) =
    {
      import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
      val futs = 1 to 100 map(_=>{Future{l.toDouble}})
      val valsFut = Future.sequence(futs)
      val vals = Await.result(valsFut,Duration.Inf)
      vals.sum/vals.length
    }

    Console.println("Locks: "+average(TestRunner(TestLocks()))+"ms")
    Console.println("Promises: "+average(TestRunner(TestPromises()))+"ms")

    Console.println("A Locks: "+averageAsync(TestRunner(TestLocks()))+"ms")
    Console.println("A Promises: "+averageAsync(TestRunner(TestPromises()))+"ms")
  }
}
```

which outputs:

> Locks: 28.0ms
>   Promises: 68.5ms
>   A Locks: 49.87ms
>   A Promises: 2307.84ms

what indicates that I have to use locks in "hot zones" and now I want to ensure if those tests are correct. Or maybe I should handle this "wait if uninitialized" case in any other way?

Answer (score 1):

A completely different approach to your answer is a concept called **Actors**.

Rather than having multiple threads, and having these threads await each other, **Actors** are like tiny little processes that communicate with each other by sending **messages**. When you're done with a piece of work, you can send a **message** to another **actor**, telling it to go and do something else.

The **Actor Model** as it's known is both highly performant *and* simple to reason about.

Scala is fortunate enough to have an incredible implementation of the **Actor Model** known as **[Akka](http://akka.io)**.

**Akka** allows you to very simply build large and complex systems - it can even handle distribution across many machines!

Here's a really simple example from the **Akka** website:

```
case class Greeting(who: String)

class GreetingActor extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  def receive = {
    case Greeting(who) ⇒ log.info("Hello " + who)
  }
}

val system = ActorSystem("MySystem")
val greeter = system.actorOf(Props[GreetingActor], name = "greeter")
greeter ! Greeting("Charlie Parker")
```

How easy is that? :-)

I strongly recommend using the **Actor Model** instead of using conventional threads and locks. Scala provides us with an incredibly powerful toolkit, I encourage you to use it!